# Buildroot, U-boot: Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: u-boot, buildroot

I'm using an image I created for Orangepi Zero with Buildroot. Trying to manually load a device tree overlay.

Here's what I do in Uboot command line:

```
load mmc 0:1 ${kernel_addr_r} /boot/zImage
load mmc 0:1 ${fdt_addr_r} /boot/sun8i-h2-plus-orangepi-zero.dtb
load mmc 0:1 ${fdtoverlay_addr_r} /boot/st7789opizero.dtb
fdt addr ${fdt_addr_r} (outputs Working FDT set to 43000000)
fdt resize 32000 (i'm not really sure but i just tried to secure the size sun8i-h2-plus-orangepi-zero.dtb + st7789opizero.dtb which is 1408+30475 = 31883)
fdt apply ${fdtoverlay_addr_r}
bootz $kernel_addr_r - $fdt_addr_r
```

After a really verbose boot attempt I get a kernel panic. Here's the full log:

```
Kernel image @ 0x42000000 [ 0x000000 - 0x563e18 ]
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 43000000
   Booting using the fdt blob at 0x43000000
Working FDT set to 43000000
   Loading Device Tree to 49fed000, end 49ffffff ... OK
Working FDT set to 49fed000

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 6.1.14 (xch@xch-Katana-GF76-11UG) (arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabihf-gcc.br_real (Buildroot 2023.11.1) 12.3.4
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fc075] revision 5 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: div instructions available: patching division code
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Xunlong Orange Pi Zero
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 16 MiB at 0x5f000000
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x000000005fffffff]
[    0.000000]   HighMem  empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x000000005fffffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000040000000-0x000000005fffffff]
[    0.000000] psci: probing for conduit method from DT.
[    0.000000] psci: Using PSCI v0.1 Function IDs from DT
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 11 pages/cpu s15764 r8192 d21100 u45056
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 130048
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:all(zero), heap alloc:off, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 488536K/524288K available (9216K kernel code, 936K rwdata, 2240K rodata, 1024K init, 273K bss, 19368K reserved)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8 to nr_cpu_ids=4.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 10 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=4
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] GIC: Using split EOI/Deactivate mode
[    0.000000] rcu: srcu_init: Setting srcu_struct sizes based on contention.
[    0.000000] clocksource: timer: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 79635851949 ns
[    0.000000] arch_timer: cp15 timer(s) running at 24.00MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource: arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x588fe9dc0, max_idle_ns: 440795202592 ns
[    0.000001] sched_clock: 56 bits at 24MHz, resolution 41ns, wraps every 4398046511097ns
[    0.000015] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 41ns
[    0.000310] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000709] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000758] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 48.00 BogoMIPS (lpj=240000)
[    0.000792] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.000985] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.001020] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.001716] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.002125] /cpus/cpu@0 missing clock-frequency property
[    0.002177] /cpus/cpu@1 missing clock-frequency property
[    0.002207] /cpus/cpu@2 missing clock-frequency property
[    0.002237] /cpus/cpu@3 missing clock-frequency property
[    0.002259] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.003102] Setting up static identity map for 0x40100000 - 0x40100060
[    0.003273] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.003294] rcu:     Max phase no-delay instances is 1000.
[    0.004014] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.015003] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.026062] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
[    0.037056] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
[    0.037144] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.037207] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (192.00 BogoMIPS).
[    0.037226] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.037239] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.037920] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.043458] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 7 rev 5
[    0.043716] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.043762] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.044526] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.046098] NET: Registered PF_NETLINK/PF_ROUTE protocol family
[    0.047386] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.048329] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.048485] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.048532] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.053688] platform 1c0c000.lcd-controller: Fixing up cyclic dependency with 1100000.mixer
[    0.070274] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.070770] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.070831] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.070884] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.071108] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    0.071192] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    0.071293] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.071310] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.071345] PTP clock support registered
[    0.071791] Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Initialized.
[    0.072817] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.081356] NET: Registered PF_INET protocol family
[    0.081621] IP idents hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.082907] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 4096 bytes, linear)
[    0.082959] Table-perturb hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.082991] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.083049] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.083228] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    0.083352] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.083406] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.083609] NET: Registered PF_UNIX/PF_LOCAL protocol family
[    0.084345] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.084383] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.084398] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.084411] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.086600] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 5 counters available
[    0.087643] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    0.087927] workingset: timestamp_bits=30 max_order=17 bucket_order=0
[    0.093730] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.093816] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.093833] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.093896] Key type asymmetric registered
[    0.093915] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    0.094058] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 246)
[    0.094086] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    0.094101] io scheduler kyber registered
[    0.156203] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 8 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.166137] lima 1c40000.gpu: gp - mali400 version major 1 minor 1
[    0.166281] lima 1c40000.gpu: pp0 - mali400 version major 1 minor 1
[    0.166378] lima 1c40000.gpu: pp1 - mali400 version major 1 minor 1
[    0.166434] lima 1c40000.gpu: l2 cache 64K, 4-way, 64byte cache line, 64bit external bus
[    0.166899] lima 1c40000.gpu: bus rate = 200000000
[    0.166933] lima 1c40000.gpu: mod rate = 297000000
[    0.167036] lima 1c40000.gpu: error -ENODEV: _opp_set_regulators: no regulator (mali) found
[    0.167487] lima 1c40000.gpu: Failed to register cooling device
[    0.167968] [drm] Initialized lima 1.1.0 20191231 for 1c40000.gpu on minor 0
[    0.170511] CAN device driver interface
[    0.171141] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: IRQ eth_wake_irq not found
[    0.171170] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: IRQ eth_lpi not found
[    0.171242] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: No regulator found
[    0.171348] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: PTP uses main clock
[    0.171387] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: Current syscon value is not the default 148000 (expect 58000)
[    0.171719] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: No HW DMA feature register supported
[    0.171753] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: RX Checksum Offload Engine supported
[    0.171775] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: COE Type 2
[    0.171792] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: TX Checksum insertion supported
[    0.171811] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: Normal descriptors
[    0.171828] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: Chain mode enabled
[    0.173334] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: Found internal PHY node
[    0.173826] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: Switch mux to internal PHY
[    0.173857] dwmac-sun8i 1c30000.ethernet: Powering internal PHY
[    0.176395] ehci-platform 1c1a000.usb: EHCI Host Controller
[    0.176461] ehci-platform 1c1a000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.177208] ohci-platform 1c1a400.usb: Generic Platform OHCI controller
[    0.177262] ohci-platform 1c1a400.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    0.178166] sun6i-rtc 1f00000.rtc: registered as rtc0
[    0.178237] sun6i-rtc 1f00000.rtc: setting system clock to 1970-01-01T03:06:51 UTC (11211)
[    0.178391] sun6i-rtc 1f00000.rtc: RTC enabled
[    0.178717] i2c_dev: i2c /dev entries driver
[    0.180861] sunxi-wdt 1c20ca0.watchdog: Watchdog enabled (timeout=16 sec, nowayout=0)
[    0.181373] ohci-platform 1c1a400.usb: irq 44, io mem 0x01c1a400
[    0.182374] sun8i-ce 1c15000.crypto: Set mod clock to 50000000 (50 Mhz) from 24000000 (24 Mhz)
[    0.182719] ehci-platform 1c1a000.usb: irq 43, io mem 0x01c1a000
[    0.182760] sun8i-ce 1c15000.crypto: will run requests pump with realtime priority
[    0.183074] sun8i-ce 1c15000.crypto: will run requests pump with realtime priority
[    0.183284] sun8i-ce 1c15000.crypto: will run requests pump with realtime priority
[    0.183477] sun8i-ce 1c15000.crypto: will run requests pump with realtime priority
[    0.183637] sun8i-ce 1c15000.crypto: Register cbc(aes)
[    0.183679] sun8i-ce 1c15000.crypto: Register ecb(aes)
[    0.183702] sun8i-ce 1c15000.crypto: Register cbc(des3_ede)
[    0.183725] sun8i-ce 1c15000.crypto: Register ecb(des3_ede)
[    0.183764] sun8i-ce 1c15000.crypto: CryptoEngine Die ID 1
[    0.184636] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    0.184665] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    0.187134] cedrus 1c0e000.video-codec: Device registered as /dev/video0
[    0.191699] NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family
[    0.191738] can: controller area network core
[    0.191840] NET: Registered PF_CAN protocol family
[    0.191860] can: raw protocol
[    0.191879] can: broadcast manager protocol
[    0.191901] can: netlink gateway - max_hops=1
[    0.192081] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    0.192126] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    0.192254] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    0.202950] ehci-platform 1c1a000.usb: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    0.204113] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.204193] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.206413] sun8i-h3-pinctrl 1c20800.pinctrl: initialized sunXi PIO driver
[    0.208003] sun8i-h3-r-pinctrl 1f02c00.pinctrl: initialized sunXi PIO driver
[    0.208339] sun8i-h3-pinctrl 1c20800.pinctrl: supply vcc-pa not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.229490] 1c28000.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x1c28000 (irq = 148, base_baud = 1500000) is a U6_16550A
[    0.247652] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.251402] printk: console [ttyS0] enabled
[    0.258395] hub 2-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.273299] sun8i-h3-pinctrl 1c20800.pinctrl: supply vcc-pg not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.316426] 1c28400.serial: ttyS1 at MMIO 0x1c28400 (irq = 149, base_baud = 1500000) is a U6_16550A
[    1.348959] 1c28800.serial: ttyS2 at MMIO 0x1c28800 (irq = 150, base_baud = 1500000) is a U6_16550A
[    1.358819] sun8i-h3-pinctrl 1c20800.pinctrl: supply vcc-pc not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.368530] spi-nor spi2.0: mx25l1606e (2048 Kbytes)
[    1.374237] 1 fixed-partitions partitions found on MTD device spi2.0
[    1.380615] Creating 1 MTD partitions on "spi2.0":
[    1.385448] 0x000000000000-0x000000200000 : "partition"
[    1.396771] sun8i-h3-r-pinctrl 1f02c00.pinctrl: supply vcc-pl not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.407405] sun8i-h3-pinctrl 1c20800.pinctrl: supply vcc-pf not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.409893] usb_phy_generic usb_phy_generic.1.auto: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    1.424854] usb_phy_generic usb_phy_generic.1.auto: dummy supplies not allowed for exclusive requests
[    1.436475] ehci-platform 1c1b000.usb: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.438663] sunxi-mmc 1c0f000.mmc: Got CD GPIO
[    1.439136] ohci-platform 1c1b400.usb: Generic Platform OHCI controller
[    1.439164] ohci-platform 1c1b400.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.442096] ehci-platform 1c1b000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
[    1.447804] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    1.453373] ohci-platform 1c1b400.usb: irq 157, io mem 0x01c1b400
[    1.471127] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    1.471817] sunxi-mmc 1c0f000.mmc: initialized, max. request size: 16384 KB
[    1.496380] ALSA device list:
[    1.499377]   No soundcards found.
[    1.503410] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    1.503460] sunxi-mmc 1c10000.mmc: allocated mmc-pwrseq
[    1.512522] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[    1.522768] ehci-platform 1c1b000.usb: irq 156, io mem 0x01c1b000
[    1.551184] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.552881] ehci-platform 1c1b000.usb: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.553810] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    1.555016] hub 3-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.555673] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 5048
[    1.556810] mmcblk0: mmc0:5048 SD16G 14.4 GiB 
[    1.561801] GPT:Primary header thinks Alt. header is not at the end of the disk.
[    1.570841] hub 4-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.573032] GPT:1 != 30244863
[    1.573041] GPT:Alternate GPT header not at the end of the disk.
[    1.573046] GPT:1 != 30244863
[    1.573051] GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
[    1.579680] hub 4-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.583233]  mmcblk0: p1
[    1.755450] sunxi-mmc 1c10000.mmc: initialized, max. request size: 16384 KB
[    1.763510] /dev/root: Can't open blockdev
[    1.768356] VFS: Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknown-block(0,0): error -6
[    1.776282] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
[    1.784682] b300        15122432 mmcblk0 
[    1.784694]  driver: mmcblk
[    1.791523]   b301           61440 mmcblk0p1 ffa48dd0-619f-49d2-aef1-52711b58fb5f
[    1.791534] 
[    1.800551] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    1.808827] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 6.1.14 #1
[    1.814759] Hardware name: Allwinner sun8i Family
[    1.819484]  unwind_backtrace from show_stack+0x10/0x14
[    1.824745]  show_stack from dump_stack_lvl+0x40/0x4c
[    1.829822]  dump_stack_lvl from panic+0x108/0x2fc
[    1.834639]  panic from mount_block_root+0x174/0x20c
[    1.839628]  mount_block_root from prepare_namespace+0x150/0x18c
[    1.845656]  prepare_namespace from kernel_init+0x18/0x12c
[    1.851165]  kernel_init from ret_from_fork+0x14/0x2c
[    1.856239] Exception stack(0xe0821fb0 to 0xe0821ff8)
[    1.861304] 1fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    1.869495] 1fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    1.877685] 1fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[    1.884312] CPU1: stopping
[    1.887024] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Not tainted 6.1.14 #1
[    1.892943] Hardware name: Allwinner sun8i Family
[    1.897645]  unwind_backtrace from show_stack+0x10/0x14
[    1.902881]  show_stack from dump_stack_lvl+0x40/0x4c
[    1.907941]  dump_stack_lvl from do_handle_IPI+0xec/0x124
[    1.913349]  do_handle_IPI from ipi_handler+0x18/0x20
[    1.918409]  ipi_handler from handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x78/0x134
[    1.924426]  handle_percpu_devid_irq from generic_handle_domain_irq+0x28/0x38
[    1.931574]  generic_handle_domain_irq from gic_handle_irq+0x74/0x88
[    1.937947]  gic_handle_irq from generic_handle_arch_irq+0x34/0x44
[    1.944140]  generic_handle_arch_irq from call_with_stack+0x18/0x20
[    1.950427]  call_with_stack from __irq_svc+0x98/0xb0
[    1.955492] Exception stack(0xe0855f68 to 0xe0855fb0)
[    1.960546] 5f60:                   00000005 00000000 00000f11 c0116040 00000001 c0e04f10
[    1.968720] 5f80: c105ee80 c0e04f58 4000406a 410fc075 00000000 00000000 c0e05014 e0855fb8
[    1.976890] 5fa0: c0107418 c010741c 60000013 ffffffff
[    1.981938]  __irq_svc from arch_cpu_idle+0x38/0x3c
[    1.986830]  arch_cpu_idle from default_idle_call+0x24/0x34
[    1.992421]  default_idle_call from do_idle+0xa4/0x120
[    1.997573]  do_idle from cpu_startup_entry+0x18/0x1c
[    2.002630]  cpu_startup_entry from secondary_start_kernel+0x118/0x120
[    2.009163]  secondary_start_kernel from 0x401015a0
[    2.014050] CPU3: stopping
[    2.016761] CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Not tainted 6.1.14 #1
[    2.022680] Hardware name: Allwinner sun8i Family
[    2.027382]  unwind_backtrace from show_stack+0x10/0x14
[    2.032617]  show_stack from dump_stack_lvl+0x40/0x4c
[    2.037678]  dump_stack_lvl from do_handle_IPI+0xec/0x124
[    2.043085]  do_handle_IPI from ipi_handler+0x18/0x20
[    2.048145]  ipi_handler from handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x78/0x134
[    2.054160]  handle_percpu_devid_irq from generic_handle_domain_irq+0x28/0x38
[    2.061307]  generic_handle_domain_irq from gic_handle_irq+0x74/0x88
[    2.067677]  gic_handle_irq from generic_handle_arch_irq+0x34/0x44
[    2.073869]  generic_handle_arch_irq from call_with_stack+0x18/0x20
[    2.080151]  call_with_stack from __irq_svc+0x98/0xb0
[    2.085217] Exception stack(0xe085df68 to 0xe085dfb0)
[    2.090271] df60:                   00000005 00000000 00001029 c0116040 00000003 c0e04f10
[    2.098444] df80: c1088000 c0e04f58 4000406a 410fc075 00000000 00000000 c0e03d80 e085dfb8
[    2.106614] dfa0: c0107418 c010741c 60000013 ffffffff
[    2.111662]  __irq_svc from arch_cpu_idle+0x38/0x3c
[    2.116553]  arch_cpu_idle from default_idle_call+0x24/0x34
[    2.122141]  default_idle_call from do_idle+0xa4/0x120
[    2.127291]  do_idle from cpu_startup_entry+0x18/0x1c
[    2.132349]  cpu_startup_entry from secondary_start_kernel+0x118/0x120
[    2.138883]  secondary_start_kernel from 0x401015a0
[    2.143766] CPU2: stopping
[    2.146478] CPU: 2 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/2 Not tainted 6.1.14 #1
[    2.152398] Hardware name: Allwinner sun8i Family
[    2.157099]  unwind_backtrace from show_stack+0x10/0x14
[    2.162334]  show_stack from dump_stack_lvl+0x40/0x4c
[    2.167394]  dump_stack_lvl from do_handle_IPI+0xec/0x124
[    2.172802]  do_handle_IPI from ipi_handler+0x18/0x20
[    2.177862]  ipi_handler from handle_percpu_devid_irq+0x78/0x134
[    2.183876]  handle_percpu_devid_irq from generic_handle_domain_irq+0x28/0x38
[    2.191021]  generic_handle_domain_irq from gic_handle_irq+0x74/0x88
[    2.197390]  gic_handle_irq from generic_handle_arch_irq+0x34/0x44
[    2.203582]  generic_handle_arch_irq from call_with_stack+0x18/0x20
[    2.209865]  call_with_stack from __irq_svc+0x98/0xb0
[    2.214930] Exception stack(0xe0859f68 to 0xe0859fb0)
[    2.219983] 9f60:                   00000005 00000000 00003a29 c0116040 00000002 c0e04f10
[    2.228157] 9f80: c105f700 c0e04f58 4000406a 410fc075 00000000 00000000 c0e05014 e0859fb8
[    2.236327] 9fa0: c0107418 c010741c 60000013 ffffffff
[    2.241374]  __irq_svc from arch_cpu_idle+0x38/0x3c
[    2.246265]  arch_cpu_idle from default_idle_call+0x24/0x34
[    2.251854]  default_idle_call from do_idle+0xa4/0x120
[    2.257004]  do_idle from cpu_startup_entry+0x18/0x1c
[    2.262062]  cpu_startup_entry from secondary_start_kernel+0x118/0x120
[    2.268596]  secondary_start_kernel from 0x401015a0
[    2.274314] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---
```

This only happens when I boot manually, autoboot works just fine. I know the last line explains what's wrong (kernel cannot find rootfs) but i don't know how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "*This only happens when I boot manually, autoboot works just fine.*" - So compare what U-Boot does when autoboot is performed versus what you enter. The answer is in front of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the issue is with command line passed to Linux kernel:

```
[    0.000000] Kernel command line:
```

it is empty. You could try to pass some root device string in uboot like this:

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p1
```

or whatever partition has been prepared by buildroot in the output image.

Comment: I will try and let you know today. Thanks

Comment: Turns out `root` was missing from bootargs. You were correct, thank you.